# Count status per month even not updated

Tags: sql

I am trying to count the number of status per month.
The trick is that it is a time series database as follow:

| status_updated_at | created_at | status | group_id | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/01/2022 | 08/01/2022 | a | group1 | 1 |
| 14/01/2022 | 08/01/2022 | a | group1 | 1 |
| 14/01/2022 | 10/01/2022 | a | group1 | 3 |
| 15/01/2022 | 15/01/2022 | a | group1 | 2 |
| 16/01/2022 | 15/01/2022 | b | group1 | 2 |
| 14/01/2022 | 08/01/2022 | a | group2 | 6 |
| 18/01/2022 | 18/01/2022 | a | group3 | 7 |
| 20/01/2022 | 18/01/2022 | b | group3 | 7 |
| 01/02/2022 | 18/01/2022 | c | group3 | 7 |
| 03/02/2022 | 03/02/2022 | b | group4 | 8 |
| 15/01/2022 | 15/02/2022 | c | group4 | 8 |

I want to count the total number of status per month in order to have something as such:

| status_month_updated_at | status | group_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | a | group1 | 2 |
| 01/01/2022 | b | group1 | 1 |
| 01/01/2022 | a | group2 | 1 |
| 01/01/2022 | b | group3 | 1 |
| 01/02/2022 | c | group3 | 1 |
| 01/02/2022 | c | group4 | 1 |
| * | a | group1 | 2 |
| * | b | group1 | 1 |
| * | a | group2 | 1 |

* those one should be taken into account as well for the month of Feb since they were not updated before.

The end goal is to display per month the total number of status per group_id, taking a picture month per month of each latest status of each id and count them.

Comment: What database are you using? Most databases have the ability to parse dates and extract a year and month, which you can use with `GROUPBY`. E.g. PostgreSQL has `EXTRACT`.

Comment: I indeed worked with a group by but, I still want to have the total of status of previous month that didn't change (hence the * in my example: they directly refer to the status that didn't change from previous month )

Answer (score 0):

Many databases have the EXTRACT function

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH from status_updated_at) as month,
    COUNT(distinct id) as count
FROM table
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH from status_updated_at)
```

Comment: Doing as such won't bring me the number of status of the previous month, would it?

Comment: not really, depending on the database you are using you may have to left join the results with a calendar table.